# Determine what element is now xpath html foreach?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I am in the middle of a process that should extract something from a HTML page. I am fairly new to DomDocument in PHP, but I got this together from some tutorials and Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, I need to know what element I am currently getting in the foreach loop below. As far as I know, the getName() function has something to do with XML, because it gives an Undefined Function Fatal error. Do you guys know any way to do this?

```
$rawdom = new DOMDocument();
$rawdom->loadHTML($page);

$finder = new DomXPath($rawdom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//dl[contains(@class, 'layout__definitionlist')]");

$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getName();
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
}
$innerHTML = $tmp_dom->saveHTML();

echo $innerHTML;
```

Comment: Please also include example input for `$page`, so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DOMElement objects, the element name is not accessible using a `getName()` function, but as [property `$tagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domelement.php#domelement.props.tagname):

```
echo $node->tagName;
```

[`getName()` is only available with SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.getname.php), which is another XML/XPath API for PHP.